# jslint and cshtml files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jslint

Is there a way of getting JSLint to look at the contents of cshtml files in an asp.net project?
I know I can extract the scripts out to js files and all is happy, but there are some one-off scripts I have that I don't really want sitting in my Scripts directory.

Answer (score 0):

jslint is just for validating your javascript code and your javascript code should be anyway in a different file than the HTML/CSHTML.

so you just have to copy the js files into the textbox. too bad that there is no possibility too upload a couple of js files, which will get validated then.

Comment: For simple, page specific javascript, this seems a little restrictive.  When the script is tightly tied to the page, I see no reason it shouldn't be IN the page.